# Is it legit to self-answer your question by quoting a comment you got?

Tags: discussion, comments, self-answer

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64586327/newly-downloaded-eclipse-installer-is-making-me-use-java-11) just now:

*Newly downloaded Eclipse installer is making me use Java 11+*

> This wouldn't be a problem for a lot of people, but I NEED to use Java 8 (jre1.8.0_261). Whenever I launch the installer (I also tried installing the DSL kit all at once) it is forcing me to use Java 11+. Mind you, I don't have any version of Java that is 11 or higher. the only installed version I have is Java 8. What the installer looks like for me. Any help would be appreciated!

Another user wrote a comment to the quesiton, which the questioner then copied verbatim as self-answer. The OP did make it clear though that another user wrote that comment.

This feels very wrong, but well, it isn't plagiarism, as the original author is clearly identified?

So, is such an answer a good thing?

Comment: Note that the original author of the comment edited the answer. 'Nuff said right there. Answering in comments is the only wrong in this scenario, and by the looks of it two or three people were making that mistake. Along comes a person who rights the wrong and basically does it in the most eye opening way possible, by quoting a comment verbatim and having nothing extra to add to it. *chefs kiss*, beautiful bit of teaching by example right there.

Comment: I've encountered this in the past. I asked them to post it as an answer, which they never responded to. Eventually, I posted it myself as a Community Wiki answer noting that it was their comment.

Comment: In this case, it were just a few minutes.